# Segmentation fault when using good data from char

Tags: c, string, if-statement, char, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str1[30];
    char str2[30];
    const char jpg[15] = "jpg"; // 1
    const char png[15] = "png"; // 2
    char *answer1;
    char *answer2;

    strcpy(str1, argv[argc - 1]);
    strcpy(str2, str1);
    answer1 = strstr(str1, jpg);
    answer2 = strstr(str2, png);
    printf("answer - %s ,  answer2 %s str1, %s str2 %s\n", answer1, answer2, str1, str2);

    // (strcmp(argv[i], "-dia") == 0)

    // if (strcmp(answer1,"jpg") == 0)
    //     printf("%s\n", answer1);

    // if (strcmp(answer2, "png") == 0 )
    //     printf("%s\n", answer2);

    if (strcmp(answer1, "jpg") == 0 || strcmp(answer2, "png") == 0)
    {
        printf("if I have a %s -> jpg || ( or an) png _> %s then print this else abort\n", answer1, answer2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ABORT\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

my output:

```
/testfiles$ ./a.out oute.png
answer - (null) ,  answer2 png str1, oute.png str2 oute.png
Segmentation fault
```

why am I getting an -->  **Segmentation fault** <-- with that one and one condition is true

```
/testfiles$ ./a.out oute
answer - (null) ,  answer2 (null) str1, oute str2 oute
Segmentation fault
```

I get a -->  **Segmentation fault** <-- with that one and both conditions are false

```
/testfiles$ ./a.out oute.jpg
answer - jpg ,  answer2 (null) str1, oute.jpg str2 oute.jpg
|| yep jpg or yep (null),
```

one condition is true there and I get no -->  **Segmentation fault** <--

The return is suppose to be NULL, so that confuses me. if I get one out of the two conditions then run the program, else abort it. In other words, there can **only be one** of the two conditions that **will** be true, else they both **will** be false. if one or the other one is true then run the program, else abort it. If both are false then abort the program.

1. if the first one is false check to see if the second one is true == good -> run program.
2. if the first one is true check to see if  the second one false == good -> run program.
3. if the first one is false and the second one is false == bad -> abort the program.

*((the other problem is **I am not even sure how to write that in C lang** ))*

Because if I write it like this, leaving everything else the same in main, just commenting out the other code then run it again.  If the first one equates to true, that being it did **not** find the "**jpg**" then it does not check the second one, it should instead Abort regardless if the second condition is true or not. leaving me with, how do I check for both conditions to be true if no then abort? in that manner.

if one is true then run else abort if both are false.

```
    if (strcmp(answer1,"jpg") != 0 && strcmp(answer2, "png") != 0 )
    {
        printf("abort\n");
        abort();
    }

    printf("still running\n");
```

I get this,

```
/testfiles$ ./a.out oute.jpg
answer - jpg ,  answer2 (null) str1, oute.jpg str2 oute.jpg
still running
```

the "**jpg**" was there, yet when I did it with a "**png**" i get this.

```
/testfiles$ ./a.out oute.png
answer - (null) ,  answer2 png str1, oute.png str2 oute.png
Segmentation fault
```

either way I write it I instead get this -->  **Segmentation fault** <-- WHY?
If this question confuses you, then that make the two of us, as this makes no sense as to why I am getting a **Segmentation fault** to me.

ADDED:

off the internet 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm
Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char string1[20];
char string2[20];

strcpy(string1, "Hello");
strcpy(string2, "Hellooo");
printf("Return Value is : %d\n", strcmp( string1, string2));

strcpy(string1, "Helloooo");
 strcpy(string2, "Hellooo");
printf("Return Value is : %d\n", strcmp( string1, string2));

strcpy(string1, "Hellooo");
strcpy(string2, "Hellooo");
printf("Return Value is : %d\n", strcmp( string1, string2));

return 0;
  }
```

It will proiduce following result:

Return Value is : -111
   Return Value is : 111
   Return Value is : 0

using char *var then coping it with strcpy then taking that pointer and checking to see
if it matches. if the two do not match the anything other then a zero 0 will return.

char and int mixed together, if they put a NULL or '\0' into the char for a no value retrun,
then why in GOD or MAN's name didn't they write a function to just ask if that char * has 
a NULL or '\0' in it then return a zero 0 so all one has to do is call that function in an 
if statment if ( checkcharfornull(var) ) giving a zero if NULL and anything esle if not, just like
strcmp does when or if it is not NULL ?????

Comment: I been looking up this **checking for NULL** problem it is everywhere people wondering, "how do I check for NULL? you'd thing that the people that decided to put a NULL as a return value in an Int or a Char * would then have written a functions to check it too, instead of all of this having to reference and dereference it and whatnot. as all I am  finding on the Internet is people asking HOW Do I Do This with just people giving questions as answers. Like this is top secret  information that the government will kill you if you tell someone the answer instead of having the other wasting time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

funny how that the answer that I put in there before was removed by a MOD stating that this --> if (number1 && *number1) { ... } <---  "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. –  shriek 12 hours ago --"

I think that he this MOD then should know more C then anyone in here to make that assessment, when in fact he is wrong, and he is a MOD??? removing correct answers for what reason other then he himself has no idea what he is looking at therefore it can't be right?

the

```
if (number1 && *number1) { ... }
```

(number1 && *number1) that is the function call and the {....} is the code that goes after it.. if I, someone that does not even know half of what I am doing know that then why  does the MOD too not know that he is a MOD ...

just because it seems that  he does not knows C and doesn't understand it, what I just learned,he then makes a judgment call saying it is not the answer because he does not understand the code, when it is in fact the answer.

So, I post the ANSWER to my own Question, and he says it is not the answer. why would I want to lie to myself? Never get anything done doing that.

Like this guy said:

*Because you are not checking the values of "answer1" and "answer2", which may be NULL. When they are null, you are then attempting to reference the data pointer to by those variables:*

```
 if (strcmp(answer1,"jpg") != 0 && strcmp(answer2, "png") != 0 )
```

and that leads to the segfault.

Then, just like he said again: " Well **if the pointer is null and that is a valid condition**, then **you need an if statement to not use the pointer when null.** –  OldProgrammer 15 hours ago "

which strstr returns a NULL if what you are looking for is not there, making it a valid condition, now put two and two together and to do what the "**OldProgrammer**" said I needed to do and I get this:

```
if (number1 && *number1) { ... }
```

giving you this:

Again the ANSWER:

```
  if (number1 && *number1) { ... }
```

which expands into this ----

```
if (answer1 && *answer1  || answer2 && *answer2)
        {
                ;
        }
        else
        {
        abort();
        }
```

it checks the VAR for string Char, dereference the pointer with a * to get 0  which is NULL 
you can't check it for NOT NULL -- blows it up every time.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not checking the values of "answer1" and "answer2", which may be NULL.  When they are null, you are then attempting to reference the data pointer to by those variables:

```
  if (strcmp(answer1,"jpg") != 0 && strcmp(answer2, "png") != 0 )
```

and that leads to the segfault.

Comment: The code should also, arguably, check that there is at least one argument other than the program name, though it will just use the program name if there are no other arguments (a little odd, but likely to be safe).

Comment: so I should go back to putting in NULL again then trying it again?

Comment: Well if the pointer is null and that is a valid condition, then you need an if statement to not use the pointer when null.

Comment: that is not the point of this code to check to be sure there is more then one thing written on the command line -- I know what I am the if statement for that one --